# PdfTable: last cell is not visible

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I use PdfPTable in the following way

```
var myTable = new PdfPTable( 3 );

foreach(var nextString in myStrings)
{

var nextCell = new PdfPCell( new Phrase( nextString, smallFont ) );
nextCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
nextCell.AddCell(nextCell);
}

pdfDocument.Add(myTable);
```

All is perfect then total cell count multiply the number of columns (3).
But when I wanted to create a table with 3 columns but 4 cells - last row is not visible.

How to solve such issue?

itextsharp 5.3.3.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To solve this issue and others I recommend the use of the `PdfPTable` method `CompleteRow()`.

This will ensure that any incomplete rows have extra cells added to make them complete so that they show up in the generated PDF.

Generally, an incomplete row will be a logic error however by using `CompleteRow()` you can easily identify where you have made these errors, and correct them.

In terms of your example:

```
var myTable = new PdfPTable( 3 );

foreach(var nextString in myStrings)
{
    var nextCell = new PdfPCell( new Phrase( nextString, smallFont ) );
    nextCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
    nextCell.AddCell(nextCell);
}

myTable.CompleteRow();

pdfDocument.Add(myTable);
```

Comment: This worked, except the CompleteRow completed the row by putting a column in that had a border around it and I wasn't able to undo that.  What I ended up having to do was either know how many columns short I was and set the column span OR know how many cells short I was and add that number of blank cells with no borders set.

Comment: You just have to add `myTable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;` for the CompleteRow method to create cells without a border.

Answer (score 2):

You can either fill the last row until it's fill or you can also set it's `ColumnSpan` to occupy the empty space.

Answer (score 1):

The last row is not visible because the last row is not complete. In your case with 3 columns and 4 cells, you need to add 2 more empty cells to make the last row complete.

Answer (score 0):

The `CompleteRow()` method will do the thing. This adds an empty cell at the end of your PDF, but you will notice it displays an empty cell with border. So, in order to avoid this behaviour, you will have to set `DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER` before calling the `CompleteRow()` method.

```
var myTable = new PdfPTable( 3 );

foreach(var nextString in myStrings)
{

    var nextCell = new PdfPCell( new Phrase( nextString, smallFont ) );
    nextCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
    nextCell.AddCell(nextCell);
}
myTable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
myTable.CompleteRow();

pdfDocument.Add(myTable);
```