# PdfPTable Can we add multiple tables one after a another with a IF statement based on the value?

Tags: c#, itext

I am having issues with PDFtable and multiple tables. It draws the first two tables fine but not any more than two. I need it to work with as many tables as possibles. Has anyone had this requirement before?

```
string firstN="";
string firstage="";
string firstNV= someValue;
int firstAgeV=110;
string firstNHobbie = someHobby;

string secondN="";
string secondage="";
string secondNV= someValue2
int secondAgeV=130;
string secondNHobbie = someHobby2;


//If value is not nothing i.e. has a value
if(firstN != "")
 PdfPTable mTablePerson1= new PdfPTable(5);
 mTablePerson1.WidthPercentage = 110f;
 mTablePerson1.AddCell("Name");
 mTablePerson1.AddCell("Age");
 mTablePerson1.AddCell(firstNV);
 mTablePerson1.AddCell(firstAgeV);

//if selected hobbies
PdfPTable mTablePerson1Hobbies = new PdfPTable(5);
mTablePerson1Hobbies.WidthPercentage = 110f;
mTablePerson1Hobbies.AddCell("Hobby");
mTablePerson1Hobbies.AddCell("firstNHobbie");

document.Add(mTablePerson1);
document.Add(mTablePerson1Hobbies);

}else if(secondN != "")
 PdfPTable mTablePerson2 = new PdfPTable(5);
 mTablePerson2.WidthPercentage = 110f;
 mTablePerson2.AddCell("Name");
 mTablePerson2.AddCell("Age");
 mTablePerson2.AddCell(secondNV);
 mTablePerson2.AddCell(secondAgeV);

//if selected hobbies
PdfPTable mTablePerson2Hobbies = new PdfPTable(5);
mTablePerson1Hobbies.WidthPercentage = 110f;
mTablePerson1Hobbies.AddCell("Hobby");
mTablePerson1Hobbies.AddCell("secondNHobbie");

document.Add(mTablePerson2);
document.Add(mTablePerson2Hobbies);

}
```

For some reason this design hides the second person's tables i.e. mTablePerson2 and mTablePerson2Hobbies. How do I make all the tables added if the firstN and secondN criteria are satisfied?

Comment: Your code misses the opening brackets.

Comment: Thanks @mkl I must have missed that.

Answer (score 1):

By default, iTextSharp only renders complete rows. If a row isn't complete, that row won't be visible. It will be as if that row doesn't exist.

iTextSharp also ignores tables without rows. If a table has no rows, no table is shown.

This is what causes your problem:

```
// You create a table with 5 columns
PdfPTable mTablePerson2 = new PdfPTable(5);
// You start the first row:
mTablePerson2.AddCell("Name");     // column 1
mTablePerson2.AddCell("Age");      // column 2
mTablePerson2.AddCell(secondNV);   // column 3
mTablePerson2.AddCell(secondAgeV); // column 4
// You add the table to the document:
document.Add(mTablePerson2);
```

As you have only added 4 cells to a row with 5 columns, that row will be dropped. As you have only one row in that table, and as that row has been dropped, no table is shown.

Change `new PdfPTable(5)` to `new PdfPTable(4)`, or add an extra cell, or use the method to complete the rows automatically, see [PdfTable: last cell is not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709428/pdftable-last-cell-is-not-visible)

I explained the problem with `mTablePerson2`, but the same answer applies to `mTablePerson2Hobbies`. In that case, you create a table with 5 columns, but you're adding only 3 cells.

Furthermore, you have something like this:

```
if (firstN != "") {
    // do something
}
else if(secondN != "") {
    // do something else
}
```

You complain that `// do something else` doesn't happen  if the `firstN` and `secondN` criteria are satisfied. This is a matter of elementary logic.

If `firstN` is not `""` than `// do something` will be executed, but not `// do something else` regardless of the value of `secondN`.

You want something like this:

```
if (firstN != "") {
    // do something
}
if(secondN != "") {
    // do something else
}
```

You should drop the `else`.

**UPDATE:**

Suppose that `c1` and `c2` are boolean values, and that you have:

```
if (c1)
   do something
else if (c2)
   do something else
```

Then this table shows what will happen:

```
| conditions | do something | do something else |
|------------|--------------|-------------------|
| c1 = false |     ---      |      ---          |
| c2 = false |              |                   |
|------------|--------------|-------------------|
| c1 = true  |     YES      |      ---          |
| c2 = false |              |                   |
|------------|--------------|-------------------|
| c1 = false |     ---      |      YES          |
| c2 = true  |              |                   |
|------------|--------------|-------------------|
| c1 = true  |     YES      |      ---          |
| c2 = true  |              |                   |
```

There is only one set of conditions that will "do something else": `c1` needs to be `false` and `c2` needs to be `true`. If `c1` is `true`, your program isn't even going to look at the value of `c2`.

You want the table to look like this:

```
| conditions | do something | do something else |
|------------|--------------|-------------------|
| c1 = false |     ---      |      ---          |
| c2 = false |              |                   |
|------------|--------------|-------------------|
| c1 = true  |     YES      |      ---          |
| c2 = false |              |                   |
|------------|--------------|-------------------|
| c1 = false |     ---      |      YES          |
| c2 = true  |              |                   |
|------------|--------------|-------------------|
| c1 = true  |     YES      |      YES          |
| c2 = true  |              |                   |
```

To achieve this, you need:

```
if (c1)
    do something
if (c2)
    do something else
```

**Update 2:**

In your comments, you claim that you want something like this:

```
| conditions | do something | do something else |
|------------|--------------|-------------------|
| c1 = false |     ---      |      ---          |
| c2 = false |              |                   |
|------------|--------------|-------------------|
| c1 = true  |     YES      |      ---          |
| c2 = false |              |                   |
|------------|--------------|-------------------|
| c1 = false |     YES      |      YES          |
| c2 = true  |              |                   |
|------------|--------------|-------------------|
| c1 = true  |     YES      |      YES          |
| c2 = true  |              |                   |
```

In that case, I'd create two methods:

```
void doSomething() {
    // code to draw one table
}

void doSomethingElse() {
    // code to draw another table
}
```

Now you can achieve what you want like this:

```
if (c1) {
    doSomething();
}
else if (c2) {
    doSomething();
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

Or you can do it like this:

```
if (c1 || c2) {
    doSomething();
}
if (c2) {
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

If you'd go to school in Belgium, this is what you would learn in the Math class at the age of 16.

Comment: Bruno I get the same behaviour even when the column count is 4 (new PdfPTable (4)) i.e. the second lot of tables are not being populated. I believe the issue is to do with how the tables are called and not an issue with column count or if table has no rows since all my tables do have complete rows. The same issue is seen even when the column is set to one i.e. data is populated into the first table and table is drawn into the PDF but no second table is drawn. Can I force a blank row to test?

Comment: Your code was badly formatted. I've taken a closer look at your code and now I see the problem. I assumed you were asking an iTextSharp question. You aren't. Your question is a 101 programming question that is so easy to solve that people probably can't believe you're not making a joke.

Comment: Thanks for the great info. what about if c1 and c2 are both true? Will the first table get drawn and the second one get drawn too immediately below it?

Comment: So my scenario is that c1 can be true on it's own and thus give me one table only however if c2 is true then c1 will always be true so always show me c1's table and then c2's table right below it.

Comment: If `c1` and `c2` are true, `do something` and `do something else` will be executed right one after the other. If you're drawing tables, they will be drawn after each other in the sequence you used. If `c1`'s table always has to be drawn if `c2` is true (regardless of the value of `c1`), then you may want to write some cleaner code.

Comment: I've updated my answer once more. You've made me curious about your nationality and age, because in most countries I know you learn this stuff at school at the age of 16.

Comment: Ahhh that makes more sense! I am an artist by nature trying to code and the right side of my brain just won't get simple maths concepts sometimes ;-( Fortunately for me I was playing football and other sporting activities at 16 ;-) I wish I went school in Belgium but then would have to use a weaker currency than the one we have ;-( Politics and demographics aside I have brushed up on my basic If logic with this primer and now got it working. It's working because my real world statements are more complex than the example given to you due to privacy issues and don't want to slip in a sensitive

Comment: word. I got it working by making sure the if statement which draws the table (document.Add(mTablePerson1Hobbies);) has the correct condition and answer which matches the persons table drawing (document.Add(mTablePerson1);). So I hope this will help anyone who is working with multiple conditions before adding tables. The only hard part is that I need 8 of these now ;-)

Comment: Many thanks for help though and full layman explanations as it helped me go back a few steps to move forward one and I am thankful for that ;-)! Regards